# dot product with unknowns of the vectors

Tags: vector-analysis

$a = (8 , y)$
$b = (2, 3)$
$c = (x, y)$

if $a \cdot c = 10$ and $b \cdot c = 8$, find the values of x and y.

I did up to

$10 = 8x i + y^2 j$

$8  = 2x i + 3y  j$

Comment: What are $i$ and $j$?

Comment: ${\bf a}\cdot{\bf b}=16+3y$, if this equals $10$ you should have no trouble finding $y$.

Comment: I think the $i$ and $j$ just the direction indicators

Comment: so sorry o_O i type wrongly

Comment: You are misunderstanding the use of $\hat i$ and $\hat j$. They are present in the **vector** form, but forming a dot product produces a **scalar**. You can think of these as $\hat i = (1,0)$ and $\hat j = (0,1)$, so $a = (8,y) = 8\hat i + y\hat j$ and $b = 2\hat i + 3 \hat j$, but $a\cdot b = (8\hat i + y\hat j)\cdot(2\hat i + 3 \hat j) = (8)(2)(\hat i \cdot \hat i) + (8)(3)(\hat i \cdot \hat j) + (y)(2)(\hat j \cdot \hat i) + (y)(3)(\hat j \cdot \hat j) = 16(1) + 24(0) +2y(0)+3y(1)=16+3y$. This is because $\hat i\cdot\hat i=\hat j\cdot\hat j =1$ and $\hat i\cdot\hat j=\hat j\cdot\hat i=0$.

Comment: Thank youuuu for your teaching :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$a\cdot b=8\cdot2+3\cdot y=16+3y$

Now solve: $16+3y=10 \Rightarrow 3y=-6 \Rightarrow \boxed{y=-2}$.

$b\cdot c=2x+3y$

Since we already found $y$ to be $-2$, we now have to solve: $2x-6=8 \Rightarrow \boxed{x=7}$.

---

**Edit**

$a\cdot c=10 \Leftrightarrow 8x+y^2=10$ $(1)$

$b\cdot c=8 \Leftrightarrow 2x+3y=8$ $(2)$

$(2)$ gives $2x=8-3y \Rightarrow x=4-\frac32y$

Plug this into $(1)$ to get $8(4-\frac32y)+y^2=10 \Rightarrow 32-12y+y^2=10 \Rightarrow y^2-12y+22=0 \Rightarrow y=6\pm\sqrt{14}$

Plug this back into $(1)$ to get: $8x+(6\pm\sqrt{14})^2=10 \Rightarrow 8x+36\pm12\sqrt{14}+14=10 \Rightarrow 8x=10-14-36\pm12\sqrt{40} \Rightarrow x=-5\pm\frac32\sqrt{14}$

The pairs $(x=-5\pm\frac32\sqrt{14},y=6\mp\sqrt{14})$ represent the accepted values for $x$ and $y$.

Comment: sorrryyyyy!!!!!

Comment: thanks a lot! so i just have to treat it like an algebra

Comment: Yes, but it's a lot of work.. :)

Comment: haha still, thank youuu :D

Answer (score 1):

You just have to solve the system:

$$\begin{cases}a\cdot b=10\\b\cdot c=8\end{cases}\implies \begin{cases}16+3y=10\\2x+3y=8\end{cases}\implies ...$$

Comment: sorry!!!!!!!!!!